# Ubuntu studio 20.04 fresh installation, can't complete language support installation

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-studio, language-support

I've recently installed Ubuntu Studio 20.04. At every session start I get a popup saying that my language support is incomplete and gives me the option to solve it. So I go to language support, choose my main language (spanish), check that it is completely installed, apply the configuration system-wide... but the popup keeps showing.

I'm supposed to have english and spanish languages installed right now. I used the `check-language-support` command, and it shows that there's nothing missing. Consequently, running `sudo apt install $(check-language-support)` doesn't install anything new. So I don't know what else to do.

I did my ubuntu installation offline (bad idea I guess). I suspect that may be the origin of the problem. But now internet is working fine and I can't fix this.

[Here's the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN52T.jpg)

[When I follow the steps it turns out that English and Spanish are already installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeMD6.png)

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include a screenshot with the popup.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson Done

Comment: I submitted an answer, kind of, but can you please let us know exactly what the terminal command `check-language-support` outputs.

Comment: Thanks! the command `check-language-support` outputs a blank line. So I don't know what's missing. If I don't get a more elegan solution I might just delete that file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer. But the file which contains that message is `/usr/share/language-support/incomplete-language-support-gnome.note`. I don't know what it is that triggers it, though.

Ubuntu Studio uses the Xubuntu desktop, doesn't it? Maybe it's Xubuntu that triggers it somehow.

OTOH, if the `check-language-support` command only results in a blank line, based on what is the "Incomplete Language Support" note triggered?

(Sorry for rather asking questions instead of a proper answer.)

I suppose that you can get rid of the prompt by simply deleting or renaming the `incomplete-language-support-gnome.note` file. Not so elegant, apparently, but atm I don't have any other idea.

Comment: Just a note, on my systems I install localization using `sudo apt install $(check-language-support -l en)` (where *en* maybe two letters language).

Comment: Yes, I also checked that. When I use 'en' or 'es' as letters, it shows a blank line. If I choose another languaje it shows some missing packages (because I have no languages installed besides english and spanish).